# PHP include (links to different websites)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress theme and in a part of my index I have a testimonials section that looks like this:

[image: Testimonials]

The idea is to link from every little image to each specific website and, of course, it is something I don't know how to do...From the admin panel (backend) you can upload the images that will be shown in the block. A maximum of 3.
The PHP code that generates that block in the index is:

```
<?php

function shortcode_testimonial($params = array(), $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "image" => '',
    "pos" => '',
    "name" => '',
"text_align" => 'text-left',
    "company" => '',
    "stars" => '',
), $params));
$content = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#', "", $content);


if (strpos($image,'http://') !== false || strpos($image,'https://') !== false) {
  $image = $image;
}
 else {
  $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'thumbnail');
  $image = $image[0];
}

$star_row = '';
if ($stars == '1'){$star_row = '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:25%"><strong class="rating"></strong></span></div>';}
else if ($stars == '2'){$star_row = '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:35%"><strong class="rating"></strong></span></div>';}
else if ($stars == '3'){$star_row = '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:55%"><strong class="rating"></strong></span></div>';}
else if ($stars == '4'){$star_row = '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:75%"><strong class="rating"></strong></span></div>';}
else if ($stars == '5'){$star_row = '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:100%"><strong class="rating"></strong></span></div>';}
if($image) $image = '<div class="testimonial_image"><img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.$name.'" class="circle" /></div><!-- .testimonial_image -->';

$testimonial='
<div class="testimonial '.$text_align.'">
    <div class="testimonial_inner">
        '.$image.'
        <div class="testimonial_text">
            '.$star_row.'
            <span class="test_content">'.$content.'</span>
            <div class="tx-div small"></div>
            <span class="test_name">'.$name.'</span>
            <span class="test_company">'.$company.'</span>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .testimonial_inner -->
</div><!-- row -->
';
return $testimonial;
}

add_shortcode('testimonial','shortcode_testimonial');
```

The next line in the code is the one that generates the images but without the possibility of link it to the respective website:

```
if($image) $image = '<div class="testimonial_image"><img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.$name.'" class="circle" /></div><!-- .testimonial_image -->';
```

I assume that this could be an easy task for a programmer but I could be wrong.
In one way or another I'll appreciate if you could help me how to achieve this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You have simply to change in this way: `<a href="url"><img src=""></a>`... but where is the destination url in your code?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the feedback...You can get that block by editing in the shortcode area in the wordpress backend. It looks like this:

Comment: [divider width="full" height="1px"]
[row]
[col span="1/3"]
[testimonial image="http://www.blastcollectibles.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/reviews-slider/silver-snail-logo.png" name="Author name" company="Company name" link=""]"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..."[/testimonial]
[/col][/row]

Comment: Editing this shortcode you can add a link in the "Author name", "Company name" or even in the comment but not in the image and that is precisely what I want to do...Do you know what could be the way to do that? Thank you!